# Google tracking event in readmore joomla button

Tags: javascript, joomla, google-analytics

Actually for display usual Read More button inside an article, we need to put this code:

```
<hr id="system-readmore" />
```

Which generates the button with related link to full article...well. Now I would like add some extra code for let me track with Google Analytic if the button has been clicked or not. For apply the code to a simple link a working code would be:

```
<a href="www.google.com" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Google Link', 'Action label', 'Additional info']);">link</a>
```

But for apply to read more how I can do ? I tried this but of course without success:

```
<hr onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Clic', 'Read More', 'Opening season']);" id="system-readmore" />
```

any idea ?

thank

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it on a global level, go to **/layouts/joomla/content/readmore.php**